# cannot send mail from localhost through php

Tags: php, xampp, localhost, pear

I am want to send an email from my website to my gmail from localhost with php. 
I have changed the files *C:\xampp\php\php.ini* and *c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini.*

in `php.ini` file i added the `extension=php_openssl.dll`and my
`[mail function]` is this:

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

on the other file,(sendmail.ini) i have done these changes:

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=gmail-password
force_sender=gmail-id@gmail.com
```

i have tryed with ports 587, 465 and 25, but i haven't managed to send an email.

my code is:

```
<?php 
require "Mail.php";
require "Mail/mime.php";
include('connect.inc');

$email = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['forget-email'] );

$sql = "SELECT * FROM database WHERE(email='$email')";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($res);

    $to      = $email;
    $from    = "gmail-id@gmail.com"; // the email address
    $subject = "Password Reset";

    $host    = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $port    =  "587";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $user    = "gmail-id@gmail.com";
    $pass    = "code";
    $headers = array("From"=> $from, "To"=>$to, "Subject"=>$subject);
    $smtp    = @Mail::factory("smtp", array("host"=>$host, "port"=>$port, "auth"=> true, "username"=>$user, "password"=>$pass));
    $msg = "You have requested a password change.\n";


if ( $row> 0 ) {
    echo "An e-mail has been send to you successfully"; 
      $mail    = @$smtp->send($to, $headers, $msg);

            if (PEAR::isError($mail)){
                echo "error: {$mail->getMessage()}";
            } else {
                echo "Message sent";
            }

}else {  
    echo "Your e-mail is not on the database. Please register.";
}
?>
```

When i call the above php file, i get this error:

> Strict Standards: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\check.php on line 18
>
> An e-mail has been send to you successfully error: authentication failure [SMTP: Invalid response code received from server (code: 534, response:
>   5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 5.7.14 then try again. 5.7.14 Learn more at 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 wx10sm2123259wjb.46 - gsmtp)]

and no email has been sent to me. 
Could you please help me?

Comment: did you actually follow the advice in the error message?

Comment: yes i followed the advice, but still no mail sent.